# Android: Cannot navigate from one Activity to another

Tags: android

I am a beginner in Android. I created an activity for the first screen, and I need to navigate to the second screen when there is a touch action.

I have this piece of code in the first activity.

```
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    startActivity(new Intent("com.vignesh.omsairam.CLEARSCREEN2"));

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Now, on touch action from the first screen, -> the second screen gets displayed for a second; then, the first screen again gets displayed for a second, and then the second screen gets loaded permanently.

I dont know why the first screen gets loaded unnecessarily.

Is there something else that I should handle in code ?? Pls help !!

Thanks !!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because, Your touch event response on both `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP`

```
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)     {
startActivity(new Intent("com.vignesh.omsairam.CLEARSCREEN2"));
}
```

Put this condition on method `onTouchEvent()`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this as well

```
 if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN )     {
    startActivity(new Intent("com.vignesh.omsairam.CLEARSCREEN2"));
    }
```